# Visibility, Fortran common variables, runtime loading of shared libraries

Tags: c, fortran, visibility, dlopen, fortran-common-block

Environment: Intel Linux, Red Hat 5.
Compiler: gcc 3.4.6
(old stuff, legacy environment with serious infrastructure, sorry)

I have multiple versions of a particular shared library (call it something like "shared_lib.so") derived from Fortran which contains a COMMON block and various computations with references to variables in that COMMON.

I need to be able to (from C code elsewhere in the end-product executable) use dlclose() and dlopen() to switch between versions of this library (within which all versions of the COMMON contents are identical) while running.  In some cases the same COMMON also appears in code which is part of a static library (call it "static_lib.a") that is also linked into the executable, and is separately maintained from my project but which has functionality which interacts with that in my shared library.

I appear to be seeing that multiple instances of the COMMON wind up in the executable, and (more importantly) that there is no linkage between the values of variables in the instance from the static library, and the values of the “same” variables in the instance from a shared library pulled in with dlopen().

What I need, in summary, is (within the overall executable) for a dlopen()-loaded shared_lib.so to be able to set/use variable XYZ in COMMON ABC, and for code in static_lib.a to set/use XYZ, and have it in effect be the same instance of XYZ, or at least for the two to be kept in synch.  Is this possible?

My compilation commands for sources in shared_lib.so are of the form:

```
g77 –c –g –m32 -fPIC –o shared_src.o shared_src.f
```

My command for building shared_lib.so is of the form:

```
gcc -g -m32 -fPIC -shared -o shared_lib.so *.o
```

My command for building the executable is of the form:

```
gcc –g -m32 –rdynamic –o exec exec.o static_lib.a shared_lib.so –lm –ldl –lg2c
```

My need is to do something from the C code of the form:

```
handle1 = dlopen ("shared_lib.so", RTLD_NOLOAD);
dlclose (handle1);
handle2 = dlopen ("shared_lib2.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
...
```

The initial startup configuration does appear to function correctly with respect to the needed variables, but the result of subsequent dlclose() and dlopen() sequences do not.  Perhaps the underlying issue is that dlopen() lacks some intelligence that gcc possesses when it is linking.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

Did/can you recompile the executable with the `-fPIC`? I found that it was necessary to compile both the shared library AND the executable with the `-fPIC` to get the `COMMON` blocks to be recognized properly.

**Long answer**

I ran into a slightly similar problem recently with COMMON blocks shared between an executable and a FORTRAN shared library. However, I'm using Intel compilers NOT the `GNU` compilers. The executable is mixed `C/C++` and `FORTRAN`.

The existing (working) Windows version of the code works by sharing the common blocks between executable and DLL through `DLLEXPORT`/`DLLIMPORT` ATTRIBUTE directives. According to the Intel compiler documentation, these attribute directives are not recognized in Linux. Indeed, the Linux Intel compiler just produces warnings for these directives.

The main changes in converting the code from Windows to Linux were replacing the Windows `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` with Linux's `dlopen` and `dlsym` routines, respectively, using `#ifdef` sections. The shared library was compiled using `-fpic` and linked with `-shared`.

While the shared library was compiled with `-fpic`, the executable was *NOT*. When running the code compiled in this manner, variables passed to the shared library through subroutine calls were passed properly, however, the `COMMON` block variables were not set correctly (or were uninitialized).

In desperation, I finally tried compiling the executable itself with the `-fpic` compiler option, and then the `COMMON` blocks were recognized properly in the shared library.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, but might help you.

Here's what the 2008 standard says about `COMMON`:

> 5.7.2.4 Common association
>
> 1 Within a program, the common block storage sequences of all nonzero-sized common blocks with the same
>   name have the same first storage unit, and the common block storage
>   sequences of all zero-sized common blocks with the same name are
>   storage associated with one another. Within a program, the common
>   block storage sequences of all nonzero-sized blank common blocks have
>   the same first storage unit and the storage sequences of all
>   zero-sized blank common blocks are associated with one another and
>   with the first storage unit of any nonzero-sized blank common blocks.
>   This results in the association of objects in different scoping units.
>   Use or host association may cause these associated objects to be
>   accessible in the same scoping unit.

In short, `COMMON` sections with the same name in the same program occupy the same storage.

A program is defined as follows.

> 2.2.2 Program
>
> 1 A program shall consist of exactly one main program, any number (including zero) of other kinds of program units, any
>   number (including zero) of external procedures, and any number
>   (including zero) of other entities defined by means other than
>   Fortran. The main program shall be defined by a Fortran main-program
>   program-unit or by means other than Fortran, but not both.

The standard doesn't say anything about static vs dynamic linking and it doesn't restrict the previous statements to static linking. Therefore, it seems the dynamically loaded library should share the `COMMON` block with the main program (which I'm not sure is even technically possible) and thus the GNU implementation is incorrect.

On the other hand, the standard also doesn't say anything about being able to load libraries dynamically. Program units "defined by means other than Fortran" should include C libraries, but that doesn't tell us how these program units are connected to the main program. Fortran, in general, is not a very dynamic language.

Of course, you can work around all this by simply not using `COMMON` blocks. If a procedure needs to read/write some data, just pass it as a parameter with intent in/out. You can also group data together in a derived type and pass it around together as a unit. Nowadays (Fortran 2003+), you can even use object oriented programming, so there is really no need for global variables anymore.

Comment: Thanks--I don't have control over the coding of either the static or dynamic portions at this time, just the C "executive" that runs them.

Comment: Also, I have verified (in the debugger, using 'dlsym') that the address of the COMMON in the static/main is not the same as the address of the same-name COMMON in the shared object.  Yet the include statements in source code for each point to the identical file, so there is no question of whether the COMMONs match.  So yes, I tend to agree that apparently what dlopen() is doing is either incorrect or incomplete. Thanks again, though.